# How to import bookmarks into Chrome-for-Android without syncing via Google account?

Tags: chrome-for-android, bookmarks, import

I am moving into a new Android 7.0 device (a Nexus 6P). On my Mac computer, I have an `.htm` file with a dozen bookmarks. How can i import these bookmarks into the stock Chrome-for-Android browser?

I am aware that Google will sync bookmarks between Chrome on a desktop and Chrome on Android via my Google account. I do **not** want to do that, because I want to avoid leaving that digital trail.

I see a number of apps on the Google Play app store, but none seems to be doing just import and nothing else.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming something like [EverSync](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.fvd.eversync) won't work, maybe you could just use the HTM file. Either post it online (as e.g., [a page in a Wordpress blog](https://raywoodcockbio.wordpress.com/2017/06/30/bookmarks/)) or save it on the device (accessed via shortcut as needed). Either way, it should open in a web browser, and its links should work.